# Adding geospatial filters to GeoServer GetFeature or GetMap request?

Tags: geoserver, wms, wfs

Translation from Google Translate:

I am developing a tool to obtain information from the cadastre. I want
to get the number of properties inside a "multypolygon". Can I do it
with parameters by GET URL?

For example:

```
http://ovc.catastro.meh.es/INSPIRE/wfsBU.aspx?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&typenames=BU.BUILDING&bbox=742438,4046840,742613,4046970&srsname=EPSG::25829&
```

Can I pass geospatial filters by URL?

Is WMS or WFS better?

Is it better to install GeoServer on my Apache?

Comment: CQL filters can be used in WFS, etc.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR** Yes, see the [GeoServer documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/filter/function.html) for details of filters.

If you simply need to know how many buildings there are in a bounding box you can use a query with `resultType=hits` like:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?request=GetFeature&version=1.1.0&typeName=topp:states&propertyName=STATE_NAME,PERSONS&resultType=hits&BBOX=-75.102613,40.212597,-72.361859,41.512517,EPSG:4326
```

You can specify a different filter by using a filter in your request. Unless you know for sure that the server is GeoServer (in which case you can use [CQL](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/cql/cql_tutorial.html)) you need to use a [OGC Filter](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/filter) either in a POST request or URL encoded in the GET request.

So you would need something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ogc:Filter xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
  <ogc:Contains>
      <ogc:Literal>MultiPolygon(((....)))</ogc:Literal>
      <ogc:PropertyName>bu-core2d:geometry</ogc:PropertyName>
  </ogc:Contains>
</ogc:Filter>
```

**Note:** You can't have a filter and a bbox filter in the same request.